# Seaborn barchart for frequency of data

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a bar chart to represent the frequency of two variables (Dead and Alive) in my test and training data. I want it to look like the second example described in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) (minus the error bars).

[image: Image showing desired output]

Currently i have

```
yfreq = pd.DataFrame(data = [Counter(Ytrain),Counter(Ytest)],
                     index = ['Train','Test'])
yfreq.columns = ['Dead', 'Alive']
print(yfreq)
>>>        Dead  Alive
    Train   384    239
    Test    165    103
```

And then for the graph

```
sns.barplot(data = yfreq)
```

Which correctly outputs a graph but does not split the data into test and training data.

[image: Image showing Currently outputted graph]

I know it has something to do with the `hue` kwarg but i can't work out how too do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. You have to melt your data frame to use x,y and hue in your seaborn barplot.

```
yfreq['type'] = yfreq.index
yfreq = yfreq.melt(id_vars = 'type')
sns.barplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value', hue = 'type', data = yfreq)
```